# Infragistics - UltraDateTimeEditor

Tags: infragistics

I am using UltraDateTimeEditor in my project and I am able to edit the date by choosing any date from the drop down. But I cannot able to edit it directly in the field.

Comment: What are the values for the Enabled and ReadOnly properties?

Comment: Hello Steve

For Enabled = True
For ReadOnly = false

Comment: It is difficult to say. By default the UltraDateTimeEditor is editable when you put on a container that is also enabled (Is your form/groupbox/panel that contain the control  enabled.Right?) The two properties above should be responsable for any locked input. I suggest to right click on the control, choose Custom Properties page and press the Modified button to show only the modified properties and check what has been changed from the default. Another debug approach could be to add a new UltraDateTimeEditor and observe if it is enablen then compare the properties